# jquery set div container height and width depending on image size

Tags: jquery

I need to set a div height and width according to the first image size within a list of 40 items (all images are the same size). To make it short function works only the first time you load the page, after visiting other pages imgSize will be undefined.

```
<div id="ulSorList"> 
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 mix">
    <div class="portfolio-list">
      <a href="#">    
          <div class="overlay-block"></div>
          <img src="/img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 mix">
    <div class="portfolio-list">
      <a href="#">    
          <div class="overlay-block"></div>
          <img src="/img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

Script

```
$("#ulSorList img:first").load(function() {
  imgSize = $(this);
  $(".portfolio-list a .overlay-block").width( imgSize.width()).height( imgSize.height() );
  alert(imgSize.width());
});
```

Everything works until you navigate throught the site (new page is loaded).

IT seems like the script is breaking at some point, so I guess that I only need to get the img size of the first list item.

I edited because since i didnt know what could be the problem the question was bad formulated.

Nothing I cant make it work, now it seems like the script isnt breaking and at least I am getting imgSize width, but I am still at the same position. Script wont function after navigaion.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean when the page is refreshed? can you specify more clearly the influence of "navigate through the site" on the image?

Comment: I mean after clicking in any menu item and a new page is load. After refreshing everything is fine

Comment: Also notice that imgSize is undefined, may this be the main problem here?

Comment: it is undefined only when menu items are clicked right?

Comment: no, is always undefined, even when everything seems to be working

Comment: by changing the way I declare the var to imgSize = $(this); imgSize returns a value, but is undefined after new page is loaded.

Comment: I think I found the problem here, script is breaking in some point, may be because there are like 30 poftfolio-list items?, I guess that if I only get the image size of the first <div class="portfolio-list"> script wont break

Comment: No, that whats not the problem, I modify the script to get only values from first image but still wont be eecuted after navigating

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("selector for menu"). on("click", function() {
    var imgSize= $(".portfolio-list a img");
    $(".portfolio-list a .overlay-block").width( imgSize.width()).height( imgSize.height() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved, may not be the best way but now its working.
The problem is that after navigating, the image was already loaded imgSize was returning the height and width before it was placed in the container.
I solved this by adding a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You are using anchor tag in jquery but where it is in the HTML code.
That's an error.

```
$(".portfolio-list>img").load(function() {
var imgSize= $(this);
$(".portfolio-list>.overlay-block").width(imgSize.width()).height(imgSize.height());
});
```